# split a video into two parts based on duration

Tags: objective-c, video, ios6, ios5

I have an app, in which i need to split a video into two parts and then concatinate one part with another video.

could any one of you tell me how to split a video into two parts based on duaration.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AVFoundation classes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/01_UsingAssets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH7-SW8) and check the editability of your video through  [UIVideoEditor classes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIVideoEditorController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: hey zahreelay, thax there. but i dont get it. could you please provide me with related code.